# page not load from top when navigate to new page in angular

Tags: angular

> this is basic angular 5 app generate by `ng new` command no library
>   added what ever i changed is mentioned below
>
> Angular Version : 5.2.0
>
> If someone want to check full code or test the app visit this link.
>   [github repo](https://github.com/NiveshSinghChauhan/angular-scroll-scale-app)

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Page1Component } from './page1/page1.component';
import { Page2Component } from './page2/page2.component';


const RoutesArray: Routes = [
  { path: 'page1' , component: Page1Component },
  { path: 'page2' , component: Page2Component }
];


@NgModule({
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Page1Component,
    Page2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(RoutesArray)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<nav>
  <a [routerLink]="['/page1']" routerLinkActive="active">Page 1</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/page2']" routerLinkActive="active">Page 2</a>
</nav>

<div class="pointer">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="arrow"></span>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**page1.component.html and page2.component.html**

```
<header>
  PAGE 1
  <!-- PAGE 2 -->
</header>

<div class="scale">
  <span>0</span>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
  <span>9</span>
  <span>10</span>
  <span>11</span>
  <span>12</span>
</div>
```

if I am on page 1 and scroll down the page and then navigate to page 2, page 2 load from the same scroll position that I have scrolled in page 1

instead of this I want that page 2 should load from the top no matter of how much I have scrolled on its previous page.

Any suggestion how achieve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add this in your **AppComponent**

First time import this

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd} from '@angular/router';
```

then in your constructor

```
constructor(private router: Router){
   //subscribes every changes of your route
   this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
       if (event instanceof NavigationEnd){
          //scroll to top
          window.scrollTo(0,0);
       }
    });
}
```